# Copy Constructor

Tags: java, copy-constructor

Hi im trying to create a copy constructor and im getting a warning. "no suitable constructor found for Money(no arguments)
    constructor Money.Money(double) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    constructor Money.Money(Money) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)"
Im doing this for class and the location where im supposed to create this constructor keeps giving me a warning.

Please help and correct if im wrong.

Here is the task my instructor has given me.

Overload the constructor. The constructor that you will write will be a copy constructor. It should use the parameter Money object to make a duplicate Money object, by copying the value of each instance variable from the parameter object to the instance variable of the new object

This is what ive written.

```
 public Money(Money object)
   {
       Money newMoney = new Money();
   }
```

Comment: so create a default (no-args) constructor

Answer (score 2):

when adding a parameterized constructor, the default constructor is removed. try adding

```
public Money()
   {
   }
```

to your code. I don't see how your constructor is copying anything though

Comment: How would i make this work
       Money newMoney = new Money();
       
       newMoney = FIRST_AMOUNT;
       newMoney = SECOND_AMOUNT;
       newMoney = THIRD_AMOUNT;       
   }

Comment: newMoney is of type money; saying newMoney = first_amount is done with the assumption that first_amount is also of type Money. Only real way to do it, is if your class Money had some kind of class level variable called money; and let us say it is a double, then you would make a setter for it and say newMoney.set(first_amount);

Answer (score 2):

The default constructor (no-argument constructor) is not automatically generated if you define one or more constructor.
You defined a constructor with one argument `Money(Money object)`, so you can't do `new Money()` without explicitly define the no-argument constructor.

BTW, creating a Money object in `Money(Money object)` is no use.
The copy constructor would be like:

```
public Money(Money object) {
  this.param1 = object.param1;
  this.param2 = object.param2;
}
```

Comment: But heres the instructions by my instructor.       "Overload the constructor. The constructor that you will write will be a copy constructor. It should use the parameter Money object to make a duplicate Money object, by copying the value of each instance variable from the parameter object to the instance variable of the new object"

Comment: makes no sense because if you overload the constructor with the same object, you can also do public Money(Money object) { return object } Money money = new Money(myOldMoney);

Comment: *[...] by copying the value of each instance variable [...]* not *[...] by copying the reference [...]*

Comment: How would i copy instances into a new object

Comment: @Daimeon, when a constructor is being invoked then it means some code has created an `new` Object of our class. You just now need to copy the state of the parameter that have been passed to this `new` Object. This answer by Kaitoy seams to perfectly answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

when u create a class, the compiler will add a default constuctor with no arguments like public Money() 2 be ur default constructor.

but after u explicitly define a constructor, the compiler won't do that any more.

so it give a hint that there isn't the applicable (actual and formal argument lists differ in length).

to fix that, u should add the constructor without arguments.